# do I need to give user and password when I do fetch rebase or pull?

Tags: git, github

I have general question on git

When I create repository and after I did clone do I need to provide user and password when I do fetch or rebase.

I guess it is related only for the fetch operation.

Can I create repository in github without user and password ? where I define the user and password in github ( or it is only when I change it to private )

Does is matter if I used https or ssh ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I create repository and after I did clone do I need to provide user and password when I do fetch or rebase.

If it is a public repo, you do not need authentication for cloning/fetching (through ssh or https).

Note: [`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) is purely a local operation, so no authentication there.

> Does is matter if I used https or ssh ?

ssh would allow to not enter anything, *if* your private ssh key is passphrase-less. If it is not, you would need an ssh-agent to cache said passphrase.

https has various credential helper in order to cache the password.
(For instance, on Windows, you have the [Git Credential Manager for Windows, or GCM](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows))

---

Reminder: those authentication data (username/password or ssh passphrase) have nothing to do with the git config `user.name`/`user.email` that will be used for authorship on `git commit`.

Comment: where i define if it is public repo or not ?

Comment: @user1365697 At its creation, or after its creation in its settings (https://help.github.com/articles/making-a-public-repository-private/, https://help.github.com/articles/making-a-private-repository-public/)

Comment: Is it possible to know in git if repo is public or not ?

Comment: @user1365697 if you don't own the repo, the easiest way is trying to access its url in a browser. If you can, it is public, if you cannot it is private. If you own the repo, again its settings can show you if it is public or not.

Comment: it is true for https but how I can check ssh

Comment: If you have an ssh url, you can deduce the https url, and then try to browse.